# Difference between createMuiTheme and getMuiTheme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In what cases would you use one and not the other? And how do they work differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

getters and setters or accessors are used in most Object Oriented Programming languages / OOP , these logics says that a getter will only return a data value but wont modify, a setter in the other hand will modify that data

> check this out [Why use getters and setters/accessors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters-accessors)